# TypeError at /accounts/tcresults

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error:

> TypeError at /accounts/tcresults
>   'ImageAndUser' object is not iterable.

I wanna show user's data from database in tc.html, but this error happen.
I wrote in views.py

```
def tc(request):
    d = {
        'tcresults': ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last(),
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)
```

in tc.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
    {% for result in tcresults %}
    　　　{{ result.tc }}
　　 {% endfor %}
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanna show the data in this part

```
{% for result in tcresults %}
        　　　{{ result.tc }}
 {% endfor %}
```

I can understand this error meaning, because I designated　latest user data , so the data is only one and it cannot be repeated.But I cannot know how to fix this.How should write it?

Traceback says

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/Desktop/accounts/views.py" in tc
  142.     return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py" in render
  30.     content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py" in render_to_string
  68.     return template.render(context, request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py" in render
  165.                 values = list(values)
```

Comment: That seems weird, `tcresults` should be a QuerySet which is iterable. I'd double check it

Comment: The error says `ImageAndUser` is not iterable, first check the type of `tcresults` variable like `type(tcresults)` and type of results coming from it

Comment: Post error message with full stack trace please.

Comment: @chachan thx, ur comments.So how should i write it?

Comment: @shivakrishna thx, ur comments.i wrote type(tcresults).  type(tcresults) was written in console.

Comment: @Selcuk thx, ur comments.i added it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object is not iterable because :

```
 ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()
```

This filter condition returned only last object in the list. One resulting element is not iterable.

I suggest you modify your code and try to print the number of items in the query set.

```
def tc(request):
    tcresults = ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()
    print tcresults, ' queryset'
    print len(tcresults), ' length'
    d = {
        'tcresults': tcresults,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/tc.html', d)
```

And update your html code like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>tc</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
    　　　{{ tcresults.tc }}
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx, ur comments.sorry,I was wrong about my views.py code.I misses .order_by('id').last()    part of  tcresults = ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user)    .

Comment: I did ur code,I got a result
<QuerySet [<ImageAndUser: user 2>, <ImageAndUser: user  3>, <ImageAndUser: user  4>, <ImageAndUser: user  5>, <ImageAndUser: user  6>, <ImageAndUser: user  7>, <ImageAndUser: user  8>, <ImageAndUser: user 11>, <ImageAndUser: user  12>, <ImageAndUser: user  13>]>  queryset
10  length

I got same error ,what should I do?

Comment: @user7523656 Updated my answer. if you are using **ImageAndUser.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('id').last()** then it will give only one result. You can just use it. Check my updated answer.

Comment: @user7523656 What exactly is you want from filter? You want to show only one last  result or all the result of request.user ??

Comment: I wanna show a user's latest data.(It means only one last result)

Comment: @user7523656 Then use my latest code. You don't need to use for loop in the template. Just write my code there as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136126/discussion-between-prakhar-trivedi-and-user7523656).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.last()` from your query in your code above.

Comment: Hi, as you can check from his comments on my answer, OP only wants last, latest result. Only one of it. This will result in the whole query set.Thanks.